# InfoPath Form Alphabetize Field Drop-down box list

Tags: infopath, list-form, dropdown

Working with InfoPath 2010 that's pulling data from an existing SharePoint (2013) List. There's a field that's a drop-down box that I would like to put into alphabetical order.  I believe I have the steps on how to accomplish this task, however, I am not sure I have it in order.

I think I would do the following:  (1.) Find the SharePoint list and sort from A to Z. I am not sure how to connect the updated list to the InfoPath Form.  Can you help me on how to connect the updated SharePoint list to InfoPath?  Or, if I going at this issue the incorrect way.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily have to even touch the list itself, just a quick modification on your data connection should do the trick.

Sounds like you've successfully created your *Data Connection* and have set up your drop-down to pull from that Data Source correct? 
If so, just do the following and your drop-down will be in alphabetical order...

1. Select *Data Connections* on your ribbon (Data > Data Connections)
2. Select your data connection and click on 'Modify...'
3. Hit Next till you get column selection...then just go down to the bottom of the dialogue and change what column you want to sort by and the sort order you'd like.

[image: InfoPath_sorting]

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thanks, @Robert Lindgren and Heckshmek.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right path, once you get new view of list all you need to do is to use XML Data connection to fetch data in an order as normal data connection use ids for ordering.

Since there's a lot of steps to follow I will pass you link to this article to follow,

[Populating form data from SharePoint List Views](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/01/15/populating-form-data-from-sharepoint-list-views.aspx)