# Alphabetize Multiple Drop-Down List Boxes

Tags: 2010, infopath, dropdown

I have an Infopath form which has several drop-down lists. These drop-down lists are being fed from a separate list (separate from the list being posted to). I need to have each of these drop-down lists to be alphabetized. Through the instructions in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80497/infopath-form-alphabetize-field-drop-down-box-list), I am able to get the first drop-down alphabetized, but then how do I get subsequent drop-downs alphabetized?

Can I utilize separate list views, sort the list ascending on the column, then attach this as a separate data connection to feed the proper drop-down list? If this does work, is it the most efficient way to make it happen (if I can create separate data connections from the same list ... not even sure if I specify a view on this or just the list itself)?

Comment: Each drop-down that feeds external data should have a data connection that you can sort by. You can have multiple data connections to the same location (with different sort order)...

Comment: Please put this as an answer. As long as it pans out, I'll select it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each drop-down that feeds external data should have a data connection that you can sort by. You can have multiple data connections to the same location (with different sort order)...

Comment: This works well. I hadn't tried re-adding the same data connection a second time. I am able to get what I needed, so thank you.